# How To Pass a hidden parameter to another component using salesforce lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, parameters

I want to send a parameter in a hidden manner from one component to another in salesforce lightning. 
The normal Syntax would be this -

```js
 navigate : function(component, event, helper) {

    //Find the text value of the component with aura:id set to "address"
    var address = component.find("address").get("v.value");

    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + address
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

but I need to pass the param value in a hidden way . Suggest answer .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [communicating with events here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_intro.htm).

Depending on the hierarchy of your components you would use either an application event or a component event. An example of passing a parameter through an application event would be:

The event file:

```
<!--c:appEvent-->
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <!-- pass context of where the event was fired to the handler. -->
    <aura:attribute name="context" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

In the component originating the parameter include the following in the html:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:appEvent"/>
```

and in the controller of that component, add the parameter and fire it:

```
var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:appEvent");
appEvent.setParams({ "context" : parentName });
appEvent.fire();
```

Then in the component where you want to receive the event, include in the html:

```
<aura:handler event="c:appEvent" action="{!c.handleApplicationEventFired}"/>
```

And in the controller of the component include the function to handle the event:

```
handleApplicationEventFired : function(cmp, event) {
    var context = event.getParam("context");
    cmp.set("v.mostRecentEvent", 
        "Most recent event handled: APPLICATION event, from " + context);

    var numApplicationEventsHandled =
        parseInt(cmp.get("v.numApplicationEventsHandled")) + 1;
    cmp.set("v.numApplicationEventsHandled", numApplicationEventsHandled);
}
```

Note that the syntax for using component events is different.